# split with file path getting wrong answer

Tags: java, split

Here is the code

```java
fullPath = "\\some_path\som_more_path\test";
basePath = "\\some_path\som_more_path";

fullPath.split(basePath);
```

I am expecting an array with 2 elements first would be an empty string and second would be "\test" as this working perfectly in javascript

But instead of the expected output some how I am getting entire `fullPath` :(

Not able to figure it out what I am doing wrong here...

Comment: you dont have enough escape characters in either string

Comment: Its because `split` param is a regex. the second part `...th\som...` is interpreted as `...th*any whitspace*som...`

Comment: Original String was `\\\\some_path\\som_more_path\\test` after escaping it became what I wrote above.

Comment: @PatrickFerreira, I was thinking the same, so what would be possible solution if I need to this

Comment: If you need to remove the `basePath` from the `fullPath`, maybe the `String.replace` function does the trick for you

Comment: What is your end goal?  If you're just trying to find root directories, Maybe use the Path object by passing your string to Paths.get() and then using path.getParent() recursively to get the base directories?  You can then do some error checking along the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `split` expects a regex, you need to quote your path so it is read as the exact value of the path and not regex expression:

```
 fullPath.split(Pattern.quote(basePath));
```

This should return 2 element array, the same as `new String[] { "", "\test" }` as you have seen in Javascript.